# text and background color are overlapping

Tags: css

Is there a way that the text can overlap when having the background-color?

```html
<span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif  !important; font-weight: regular; color=black; background-color:#E0E0E0;  padding: 5px; ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation </span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9zbjye3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the inline nature of `span`.Give a line-height to avoid overlapping

```html
<span style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif  !important; 
font-weight: regular; color=black; background-color:#c44dff; 
 padding: 5px;line-height:30px ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
 ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation </span><br><br>
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid the whitespace in between, maybe using a div ?